# How to run kubectl commands inside a container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

In a container inside a pod, how can I run a command using kubectl? For example, if i need to do something like this inside a container:

> kubectl get pods

I have tried this : In my dockerfile, I have these commands :

```
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
RUN sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

> EDIT : I was trying the OSX file, I have corrected it to the linux binary file. (corrected by @svenwltr

While creating the docker file, this is successful, but when I run the kubectl get pods inside a container,

```
kubectl get pods
```

I get this error :

> The connection to the server : was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

When I was deploying locally, I was encountering this error if my docker-machine was not running, but inside a container how can a docker-machine be running?

Locally, I get around this error by running the following commands:
(dev is the name of the docker-machine)

```
docker-machine env dev
eval $(docker-machine env dev)
```

Can someone please tell me what is it that I need to do?

Comment: I am confused. Do you run that container in Kubernetes or in Docker machine?

Comment: @svenwltr - I am running kubernetes locally on minikube, and it suggests to use a docker deamon in the kubernetes VM.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would use kubernetes api, you just need to install curl, instead of `kubectl` and the rest is restful.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

Im running above command on one of my apiservers. Change the **localhost** to **apiserver ip address/dns name**.

Depending on your configuration you may need to use ssl or provide client certificate.

In order to find api endpoints, you can use `--v=8` with `kubectl`.

example:

```
kubectl get pods --v=8
```

Resources:

Kubernetes [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.5/)

**Update for RBAC:**

I assume you already configured rbac, created a service account for your pod and run using it. This service account should have list permissions on pods in required namespace. In order to do that, you need to create a role and role binding for that service account.

Every container in a cluster is populated with a token that can be used for authenticating to the API server. To verify, Inside the container run:

```
cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

To make request to apiserver, inside the container run:

```
curl -ik \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
     https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

Comment: I tried your suggested answer, but it gives me another error - 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 8080: Connection refused. Although am able to do a kubectl get pods. Also, when I run the command netstat -atn to check the open ports, there are no ports shown open on the particular ip.

Comment: @Tarun 192.168.99.100 is the api server ip address right? btw I just tested it on my setup, its working fine.

Comment: Yes, I am running kubernetes on minikube. Its the minikube ip. I had made a mistake,  I was trying port 8080. But, then when I tried a kubectl config view, it shows port 8443. Also, when I checked the api endpoints, it shows "https" for mine. Is that the same for you? When I try with https, I get a ssl error(curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain). I am trying to resolve it, will update as soon as i resolve the error.

Comment: @Tarun Im on production environment, try `--insecure` with your curl, Do you have your `ca.pem` and `client.pem` and `client-key.pem`? if so you can try : `curl https://ip:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --cacert ca.pem --insecure --key client-key.pem --cert client.pem`

Comment: I tried --insecure but it does not resolve the problem, Ya, I did not have .pem files, will try adding them and update asap. Again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: While that answer allows you to query API it doesn't solve the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651673/2335253 for real answer.
To play around with API I'd suggest using 'kubectl proxy' which you could run on you local machine though

Answer (score 43):

Bit late to the party here, but this is my two cents:

I've found using `kubectl` within a container much easier than calling the cluster's api

(Why? Auto authentication!)

Say you're deploying a Node.js project that needs `kubectl` usage.

1. Download & Build `kubectl` inside the container
2. Build your application, copying `kubectl` to your container
3. *Voila!* `kubectl` provides a rich cli for managing your kubernetes cluster

[Helpful documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)

--- EDITS ---

After working with `kubectl` in my cluster pods, I found a more effective way to authenticate pods to be able to make k8s API calls. This method provides stricter authentication.

1. Create a `ServiceAccount` for your pod, and configure your pod to use said account. [k8s Service Account docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)
2. Configure a `RoleBinding` or `ClusterRoleBinding` to allow services to have the authorization to communicate with the k8s API. [k8s Role Binding docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding)
3. Call the API directly, or use a the [k8s-client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client) to manage API calls for you.  I HIGHLY recommend using the client, it has automatic configuration for pods which removes the authentication token step required with normal requests.

When you're done, you will have the following:
`ServiceAccount`, `ClusterRoleBinding`, `Deployment` (your pods)

Feel free to comment if you need some clearer direction, I'll try to help out as much as I can :)

#### All-in-on example

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-101
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-101
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: k8s-101-role
      containers:
      - name: k8s-101
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: salathielgenese/k8s-101
        ports:
        - name: app
          containerPort: 3000
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-101-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: k8s-101-role
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: k8s-101-role
```

The `salathielgenese/k8s-101` image contains `kubectl`. So one can just log into a pod container & execute `kubectl` as if he was running it on k8s host: `kubectl exec -it pod-container-id -- kubectl get pods`

Comment: Can you descripte the part on how to connect the api a bit more in detail?

Comment: @Berndinox sure! All of the `kubectl` commands can be input over command line. Using Node's fork child process, you can execute these commands. Make sure to initialize the `kubectl proxy` before executing other commands. 

To build the docker image with `kubectl`: https://pastebin.com/6a8kp6aR

Comment: As a k8s beginner, those directives above sounds magic but I found some help to translate it into some configuration - https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C09NXKJKA/p1555058986037900?thread_ts=1555049081.017200&cid=C09NXKJKA. So I'll edit to provide an example.

Comment: @mster Could you help me with the Dockerfile? I want to install kubectl in the container I'm getting the error: `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: circular dependency detected on stage: kubectl`. This is my Dockerfile: https://pastebin.com/Lqb1py64

Comment: Never ever give Cluster-Admin if it's not needed. Apart from that, the solution seems viable.

Answer (score 21):

#### First Question

> `/usr/local/bin/kubectl: cannot execute binary file`

It looks like you downloaded the OSX binary for `kubectl`. When running in Docker you probably need the Linux one:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
```

#### Second Question

If you run `kubectl` in a proper configured Kubernetes cluster, it should be able to connect to the apiserver.

`kubectl` basically uses this code to find the apiserver and authenticate: [github.com/kubernetes/client-go/rest.InClusterConfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/fcdf37233b57445e4a6a4038ec580e9aaac931de/rest/config.go#L274)

This means:

- The host and port of the apiserver are stored in the environment variables `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT`.
- The access token is mounted to `var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`.
- The server certificate is mounted to `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`.

This is all data `kubectl` needs to know to connect to the apiserver.

Some thoughts why this might won't work:

- The container doesn't run in Kubernetes.

  - It's not enough to use the same Docker host; the container needs to run as part of a pod definition.
- The access is restricted by using an [authorization plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/) (which is not the default).
- The service account credentials are overwritten by the [pod definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_podspec) (`spec.serviceAccountName`).

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I made the necessary changes for linux. But, I still get another error, will update the question. :)

Comment: I updated the answer. Not sure if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Haven't been able to try this, will update asap. But, thanks for your response, it definitely gave me a much better understanding of the issue :)

Comment: interestingly I have found the linux kubectl (as per the link you mentioned) to run on big sur...

Answer (score 9):

I just faced this concept again. It is absolutely possible but let's don't give "**cluster-admin** privileges in with **ClusterRole** that container for security reasons.

Let's say we want to deploy a pod in the cluster with access to **view** and **create** pods only in a specific namespace in the cluster. In this case, a `ServiceAccount` could look like:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: spinupcontainers
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: spinupcontainers
  namespace: <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: spinupcontainers
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: spinupcontainers
  # "namespace" omitted if was ClusterRoles because are not namespaced
  namespace: <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
  labels:
    k8s-app: <YOUR_APP_LABEL>
rules:
#
# Give here only the privileges you need
#
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - delete
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: spinupcontainers
  namespace: <MY_NAMESPACE>
  labels:
    k8s-app: <MY_APP_LABEL>
---
```

If you apply the service account in your deployment with `serviceAccountName: spinupcontainers` in the container specs you don't need to mount any additional volumes secrets or attach manually certifications. **kubectl** client will get the required tokens from  `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`. Then you can test if is working with something like:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <your-container-with-the-attached-privs> -- /kubectl get pods -n <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
NAME.        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod1-0       1/1     Running   0          6d17h
pod2-0       1/1     Running   0          6d16h
pod3-0       1/1     Running   0          6d17h
pod3-2       1/1     Running   0          67s
```

or permission denied:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <your-container-with-the-attached-privs> -- /kubectl get pods -n kube-system
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:spinupcontainers" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Tested on:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <your-container-with-the-attached-privs> -- /kubectl versionClient Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you shows us the Dockerfile(spinupcontainers) you configured

Answer (score 3):

Combined from all above. This did the trick for me.
Retrieving all pods from within a container.

```
curl --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"  https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#-strong-read-operations-pod-v1-core-strong- for the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

To run kubectl commands inside a container.
It would take 3 steps

1. Install kubectl

```
RUN printf '[kubernetes] \nname = Kubernetes\nbaseurl = https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64\nenabled = 1\ngpgcheck = 1\nrepo_gpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg' \
  | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo \
  && cat  /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo \
  && yum install -y kubectl
```

2. Create ClusterAdminRole Binding role for service account

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mysa-admin-sa
  namespace: mysa
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: mysa-admin-sa
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: mysa-admin-sa
    namespace: mysa
```

3- Example of cronjob configuration

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scaleup
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  schedule: "00 5 * * 1-5"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: mysa-admin-sa
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
          - name: scale-up
            image: myimage:test
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", "mykubcmd_script >>/mylog.log"]
```

Comment: How you configured the dockerfile for docker image to kubectl etc...

Comment: you would need to have kubectl client installed on the docker image. For e.g. for centos based OS you need to add this line in Dockerfile.                                

`RUN printf '[kubernetes] \nname = Kubernetes\nbaseurl = https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64\nenabled = 1\ngpgcheck = 1\nrepo_gpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg' \
  | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo \
  && cat  /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo \
  && yum install -y kubectl`

Answer (score -5):

1. To run a command inside a pod with single container use below command

kubectl --exec -it <pod-name> -- <command-name>

2. To run a command inside a pod with multiple containers use below command

kubectl --exec -it <pod-name>  -c <container-name> -- <command-name>