# What is the best way to exec into another container and access its directory?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a container running inside a pod and I want to be able to monitor its content every week. I want to write a Kube cronjob for it. Is there a best way to do this?

At the moment I am doing this by running a script in my local machine that does `kubectl exec my-container` and monitors the content of the directory in that container.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl exec my-container` sounds perfectly fine to me. You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642170/kubernetes-how-to-run-kubectl-commands-inside-a-container) if you want to run `kubectl` in a pod (Kubernetes CronJob).

There are other ways but depending on what you are trying to do in the long term it might be an overkill. For example:

- You can set up a [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) or [tail/grep sidecar](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent) (or `ls`, if you are using a binary file?) to send the content or part of the content of that file to an Elasticsearch cluster.
- You can set up [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) in [Kubernetes](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Ckubernetes_sd_config%3E) to scrape metrics on the pod mounted filesystems. You will probably have to use a custom exporter in the pod or something else that exports files in mount points in the pod. [This is a similar example](https://github.com/giantswarm/kubernetes-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/prometheus/node-directory-size-metrics/daemonset.yaml).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script in another sidecar of your pod.

- Define a empty directory `volume`
- Mount this `volume` as your content directory
- Also mount this directory to sidecar, so that it can access and able to monitor.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: monitor-by-sidecar
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes: # empty directory volume
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: container-which-produce-content # This container is main application which generate contect. Suppose in /usr/share/nginx/html directory
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
      - while true;
        do 
        echo "hello world";
        echo "----------------" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html;
        cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html;
        done

  - name: container-which-run-script-to-monitor # this container will run your monitor scripts. this container mount main application's volume in /pod-data directory and run required scripts.
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - while true; 
      do 
      echo "hello"; 
      sleep 10;
      ls -la /pod-data/;
      cat /pod-data/index.html;
      done
```

### Example Description

- First container(named *container-which-produce-content*) is main application, which mount a `emptyDir` volume in `/usr/share/nginx/html`. In this directory main application will generate data.
- Second container(named *container-which-run-script-to-monitor*) will mount same `emptyDir` volume (named *shared-data* which also mounted by main application in `/usr/share/nginx/html` dir) in `/pod-data` directory. This `/pod-data` contains whole data which main application generated in `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory. You can then run your scripts on this directory.