# Kubernetes: How can i run kubectl command inside cronjob pod in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I have written shell script for k8s cronjob which uses kubectl command to get namespaces with needed parameters (like age, name etc). But i have an issue like this: ***Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope***. I have tried to write a ClusterRole, but it didn't work too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run kubectl commands inside a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642170/how-to-run-kubectl-commands-inside-a-container)

Comment: you were in the right path `I have tried to write a ClusterRole, but it didn't work too.`. What is the error? why do you thinkit does not work ? ,have you tried `kubectl auth can-i  get ns  --as  system:serviceaccount:default:default` ?